# A short story about an old pirate pawning a ship in a bottle

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the mid-70s, I read this story in high school while waiting for a classmate to do our homework at our local public library. I pulled out a random thick book and started reading the first few lines. It was a short story about an old pirate carrying a small ship in a bottle trying to borrow money from a pawnbroker. The pirate left the ship for few days with one condition only: "Never remove the cork from the bottle". A few days later, the pawn shop owner realized that the ship looked real. Then, on a stormy night "inside the bottle", the owner ignores the pirate's warning and removes the cork to save the ship that is about to be wrecked, and the man ends up inside the galley of the ship, oar tied, paddling along with skeletal rowers.

Few days after the reading, I tried to locate the book, but I couldn't. Would this story sound familiar?

Comment: That's got a *Twilight Zone* vibe, but pretty sure those stories, when published in print, were in fairly thin paperbacks.

Comment: The description seems like something that L. Sprague de Camp might have written.

Comment: 2bingo Mehndra  A "galleon" would be a sailing ship.  A "galley" would be a ship largely propelled by rowing, and late medieval and early modern galleys were often rowed by convicts or slaves chained in place.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Thanks for the clarification. I'm not an expert on ships and I don't remember the exact words from the book, thus, I just changed galleon with ship.